# Stopping hive from writing temp files to s3

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hive, cloudera

How do I stop Hive from writing temporary files to s3 when doing an INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE  query.

I found a property in hive-default.xml

```
<property>
    <name>hive.exec.skips3scratch</name>
    <value>true</value>
    <description>Do not write temp files to S3 scratch space. This will
        increase the performance by avoiding multiple writes in S3, but can
        corrupt the table or partition being written to, esp. if the job
        fails.
    </description>
</property>
```

I set this in hive-site.xml, but it still seems to write temp files to s3.

Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: I found this http://community.cloudera.com/t5/Batch-SQL-Apache-Hive/hive-s3-andhive-exec-skips3-scratch/td-p/641 That hive property seems to be exclusive to the amazon flavor of Hive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon reading that cloudera forum page here is one possible workaround:

For Hive tables that are defined with data in S3, in order to do an 'INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE ...' create a temporary local table using 'like', write the data to the local hdfs and then use distcp to move the data to s3.

Note:
Things to keep in mind. EMR version of Hive has been modified to work well with S3.
Apache Hive will read data from S3, but has issues with writing to S3 (because it tries writing temporary files to s3 and has issues with reading them back). Above mentioned approach is one workaround to this problem.

source: http://community.cloudera.com/t5/Batch-SQL-Apache-Hive/hive-s3-andhive-exec-skips3-scratch/td-p/641